# Cannot read property error when calling a member function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following module `Dog`. I want to call the member function `wagTail()` every time I call `walk()`, because it is a happy dog.

```
class Dog {
  constructor(name){
     this.name = name
  }

  walk(){
    doAsyncStuffToMoveLegs((error) => {
      if(!error) {
        this.wagTail()
      }
    })
  }

  wagTail(){
    // initiate tail wagging :)
  }
}
module.exports = {Dog: Dog}
```

I get the following error: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'wagTail' of undefined.` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to capture the `this` of `walk` and use it inside the `doAsyncStuffToMoveLegs` callback, like `var that = this; doAsyncStuff(... that.wagTail(); ... )`

Comment: thanks, `that` worked for me